# How to check for ambiguous grammar if you don't know the string

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, ambiguity

Let's say I have a CFG grammar $G$ which describes some rules for language generation. How can you tell that grammar can generate ambiguous results for a string if you don't know that string? I know how to check for ambiguity when you're given a particular string but what about the cases when it's not? Is there any algorithm to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot tell that a context-free grammar is ambiguous, since the problem is undecidable. This can be proved by a [straightforward reduction](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/4353/40) from the Post correspondence problem, for example. What this means is that there is *no* algorithm that, given a context-free grammar, decides whether it is ambiguous or not.

Answer (score -1):

My answer is this, you can not check for ambiguity if no string is given, because there is no algorithm till now to check for ambiguity.

Comment: What's the difference from [the existed answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/84480/83244)?